# wordpress Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxx/functions.php on line 202

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this error in my wordpress webpage:

> wordpress Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxx/functions.php on line 202

Here is the relevant code:

```
200 class pont_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
201  function end_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args){
202    $output=preg_replace("/([^>]{1})(<\/a>)/", "$1<span></span>$2", &$output);
203    $output.="</li>\n";
204  }
```

Comment: Remove the `&` before `$output` in the `preg_replace` line. Also see duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Remove & from &$output & give a try. :)

```
function end_el($output, $category, $depth, $args) {.... }
```

and in

```
$output=preg_replace("/([^>]{1})(<\/a>)/", "$1<span></span>$2", &$output);
```

Comment: thank you very match Vijayakumar Selvaraj,all works

Comment: solved.thank you Vijayakumar Selvaraj,all works good,realy thank you